# Intel AVCSR - (Lip reading to augment Voice Recognition)

Tags: opencv, voice-recognition

I am interested in using a library that supports lip reading to augment audio/voice recognition. I found out that Intel's AVCSR (which was bundled with OpenCV library) would be an interesting option to consider. Would there be any other libraries that can be used to achieve the same (lip reading to augment voice recognition)?

Also I have not been able to locate a source to download this library from. I already tried the OpenCV package from SourceForge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) but it does not seem to have the AVCSR packages/files. Could someone who has already worked with something similar point me to the place where I can find these source files (either within OpenCV or elsewhere)?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that AVCSR package was gone long ago. Nobody knows about it now, and OpenCV has not supported audio processing, at least from 2.0 and above

Comment: @vasile Thank you for the comment. Yeah, the OpenCV packages do not seem to carry this for the last several versions (as you mentioned). Any idea why they got rid of this stuff or where it went?

Comment: Nope. Never seen it. I suppose it was an experimental feature, removed before even being officially published.